# How to load every kind of obj 3D models in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

I have tried to load the 3D models using objloader, mtlloader and orbitcontrols. But for every model I have to tweek the setting of the position of the camera to fit the object, is there a way to auto place the camera and object so that I can use one single code to dynamically load all kinds of models?

This is what I've tried.

```
new MTLLoader( manager )
                    .setPath( './' )
                    .load( 'model.mtl', function ( materials ) {

                        materials.preload();

                        new OBJLoader( manager )
                                .setMaterials( materials )
                                .setPath( './' )
                                .load( 'model.obj', function ( object ) {
                                    object.position.y -= 200;
                                    object.position.x -= 100;
                                    object.position.z += 300;
                                    scene.add( object );
                                }, onProgress, onError );

                    } );
```

The positioning of the object is set hardcoded, which will not work wuth the other models? Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to auto place the camera and object so that I can use one single code to dynamically load all kinds of models?

Yes, you basically apply approaches used by professional model viewer software. One popular example is from the following `three.js` based [glTF-Viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/). It's open source and the relevant code section is:

```js
const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object);
const size = box.getSize(new THREE.Vector3()).length();
const center = box.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());

controls.reset();

object.position.x += (object.position.x - center.x);
object.position.y += (object.position.y - center.y);
object.position.z += (object.position.z - center.z);
controls.maxDistance = size * 10;
camera.near = size / 100;
camera.far = size * 100;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

camera.position.copy(center);
camera.position.x += size / 2.0;
camera.position.y += size / 5.0;
camera.position.z += size / 2.0;
camera.lookAt(center);

controls.saveState();
```

The idea is to compute the AABB from the loaded 3D object and then derived the respective center and size. These data can be used to position the 3D object at the origin and to adjust camera and controls parameter. Check out the [setContent()](https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-gltf-viewer/blob/1b1cbafdfd75ea02e2e12b87d8f8f8b7a33d0641/src/viewer.js#L216-L275) of the project for a complete example.